# Установка куки для других сайтов

Tags: php, cookie

По адресу bdkurs/dick есть index.php файл в котором устанавливаю куки

```
header('Set-Cookie: mycoockie=newcookie; expires=Tue, 30-Mar-2017 19:19:16 GMT;path=/;domain=vk.com');
```

При переходе на страницу, пришел ответ куки для домена vk.com
[image]
В итоге куки нет
[image]
Не знаю в чем косяк. Хотя если например зайти в сохраненные куки http://ru.stackoverflow.com. Там есть куки с других доменов. В vk.com моего куки тоже нет.
[image]

Comment: Хотя куки без домена для bdkurs ставится без проблем

Comment: Может связано с тем что сам сервер запущен на Openserver в локалке

Comment: Нельзя установить куки сторонних сайтов.

Comment: Конечно нельзя, это же была бы громаднейшая дыра в безопасности

Comment: Если с vk.com удалить все cookie mail.ru, при обновлении будет от mail.ru 2 куки. При переходе на страницу mail.ru и обратно на vk.com добавляется еще 5 кук сверху, эт как?

Comment: @Krezo, зайдите в браузере в инструменты разработчика, во вкладку Сеть и загрузите страницу vk.com/mail.ru и обратите внимание с каких сайтов грузятся файлы.